# ES custom dynamic mapping field name change

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a use case which is a bit similar to the ES example of [dynamic_template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-dynamic-mapping.html#dynamic-templates) where I want certain strings to be analyzed and certain not.

My document fields don't have such a convention and the decision is made based on an external schema. So currently my flow is:

- I grab the inputs document from the DB
- I grab the approrpiate schema (same database, currently using **logstash** for import)
- I adjust the name in the document accordingly (using logstash's ruby mutator):

  - if not analyzed I don't change the name
  - if analyzed I change it to `ORIGINALNAME_analyzed`

This will handle the analyzed/not_analyzed problem thanks to dynamic_template I set but now the user doesn't know which fields are analyzed so there's no easy way for him to write queries because he doesn't know what's the name of the field.

I wanted to use field name aliases but apparently ES doesn't support them. Are there any other mechanisms I'm missing I could use here like field rename after indexation or something else?

For example [this ancient thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/zMCyOcRLiQ8) mentions that `field.sub.name` can be queried as just `name` but I'm guessing this has changed when they disallowed `.` in the name some time ago since I cannot get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the user only create queries with the original name. I believe you have some code that converts this user query to Elasticsearch query. When converting to Elasticsearch query, instead of using the field name provided by the user alone use both the field names `ORIGINALNAME` as well as `ORIGINALNAME_analyzed`.  If you are using a `match` query, convert it to `multi_match`. If you are using a `term` query, convert it to a `bool` `should` query. I guess you get where I am going with this.

Elasticsearch won't mind if a field does not exists. This can be a problem if there is already a field with `_analyzed` appended in its original name. But with some tricks that can be fixed too.

Comment: yeah that's how I'm doing it now - actually I'm also storing the name mapping in ES so I can easily get myself the actual name,  just was hoping there's something built-in :-)

Comment: Are you only using `multi_match` queries?

Comment: actually I'm using quite a lot of different types of queries and aggregations. Starting to think it might be easier just to analyze all string fields and be done with it :-)